# Exit enumeration in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I'm just trying to remove a numbered bullet. That's it.

[image]

I have tried so many things and I still can't complete this trivial task. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the "1." (this will put the cursor outside of the table). Then go up to where in your screen shot it says "Plain Layout" (but after you click on the "1." it will say "Enumerate") and change it to "Standard".